# PyCharm gutter navigation icons

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, pyramid, chameleon

Hi I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.  I have a number of existing pyramid projects which I have used the "open directory" option in PyCharm 5 to access.  This creates a "project" entry in PyCharm project manger, but I noticed that none of the helpful template/source navigation icons appear in the left gutter of the file editor.

At first I thought maybe because I was using Chameleon, but I recently created a new project from within PyCharm, and the icons appear.  So I'm guessing there is some sort of setting that when creating a new project from within PyCharm is enabled.  However, I can't find out what it is.  I've looked through the ".idea" folder comparing the files of this newly created project to those of the ones created via "open directory" and I can't spot anything obvious.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direct please?

Thanks Keith

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. Just for fun, can you try creating a Pyramid run configuration?

Comment: @PaulEveritt thanks for taking the time to reply.  I'm not sure exactly what you are suggesting.   However, if you are talking about the run/debug configuration that you use to kick pserver off from within PyCharm, I do have them setup.  I've compared it against one for an project created by PyCharm itself and they look identical.  Also I'm not sure how this would actually affect the IDE since you don't need to have pserve running for the icons to appear in the gutter.  So I guess I'm missing what you are actually asking for

Comment: One more point to add, just to make sure...are you using PyCharm Community Edition or Professional Edition? Pyramid support is for the latter.

Comment: @PaulEveritt yes it's the Professional edition.  As I mentioned it works for a new projects, just not for projects which are created using the "open" option.